# [MyObject myObjectWith: ...]

Tags: objective-c, constructor, initialization

Does someone knows how to make this kind of "class auto instantiator":

```
myDict = [NSDictionnary dictionnaryWithCapacity: 0];
```

I can't find any resource on this (maybe I just don't know the terminology)

Comment: That's a static method.

Comment: Instance/Class Methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean... Do you mean a class method to create an object?

```
@implementation myClass

+(myClass *)myClassWithParameter:(int)whatever
{
    myClass instance = [[myClass alloc] init];
    [instance doWhatever:whatever];
    return instance;
}
```

Comment: Yes I mean a class method to return the instantiated object of this class

Comment: Very simple actually, I didn't even though about a simple class function. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's a class method (denoted by "+" instead of "-").

```
+ (MyClass *)myClassWithObject:(ObjectType *)object
{
    //do whatever you need to make an instance of MyClass using that object's data
    return myClassInstance;
}
```

Comment: Its a class method, not actually static method to be super-correct

Comment: Oh sorry. I come from a heavy Java background. I'll edit it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's just a static method which you can use in place of alloc/init. In objective-c, static method are called on an instance of the meta-class which is why they are sometimes called "Class methods".

```
@implementation TheBestObjectEver
+ (instancetype)makeMeAnObject {
    return [[self alloc] init];
}
@end
```

---

```
TheBestObjectEver *myObject = [TheBestObjectEver makeMeAnObject];
```